# Nexus 3 REST API to download artifacts

Tags: nexus, sonatype, nexus3

Nexus 2.x had a REST API to download artifacts like below but no longer works for Nexus 3.x

`wget "http://local:8081/service/local/artifact/maven/redirect?g=com.mycompany&a=my-app&v=LATEST" --content-disposition`

Has the API changed to something else for on Nexus `3.0.0-03`?

Answer (score 5):

Currently this does not exist in Nexus 3. It is on our Roadmap.

*Edit: Since Nexus 3.3 API functionality has been added. See https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/rest-and-integration-api for more information.*

Comment: Has this changed in the past year?

Comment: My answer is from November 15th, not November 2015 :). Still the same status.

Comment: is there any other API to download artifacts? we need this after upgrading for our ansible scripts. the ansible maven module had problems.

Comment: Likely it needs the URLs it uses updated, as these are different between Nexus 2 and 3. If you share it with me I can maybe help you out :)

Comment: This has now changed, take a look at my other answer to this question if you are interested.

Answer (score 2):

The URL for downloading a Maven asset directly with Nexus3 looks roughly like this:

`https://nexus.example.local/service/rest/v1/search/assets/download?sort=version&repository=snapshots&maven.groupId=com.example.group&maven.artifactId=my-artifact&maven.baseVersion=1.0.0-SNAPSHOT&maven.extension=jar`

(Tested with Nexus v3.28)

For more options and other repository formats, check out the Swagger interface that's available in the administration area of Nexus.

Comment: Today it is the correct answer. Thank you @philippn!

Answer (score 1):

At this time, the REST API has been released as beta. You can get more information and give us feedback by going to this link: http://blog.sonatype.com/nexus-repository-new-beta-rest-api-for-content

Comment: with maven repository, the search API works perfectly for hosted repository but not with proxy and group repository.

Answer (score 1):

just for this case, I created a PHP script that returns HTTP redirect to the location of the artifact.
feel free to use 
https://github.com/maozza/nexus3-redirector

Answer (score 0):

None of the existing answers worked for me - all of them return 404. I have a **proxy** repository configured in Nexus OSS 3.38. The URL that successfully cached and downloaded the artifact was as follows (but it requires a specific version to be known):

`https://<nexus-url>/repository/<repo-name>/<group/as/slashes>/<artifact>/<version>/<artifact>-<version>.<format>`

for example slf4j-api:

`https://nexus.url/repository/maven-proxy/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/2.0.7/slf4j-api-2.0.7.jar`

Hope this helps someone.